# Ubuntu 16.04 with KDE frozen after being locked

Tags: 16.04, kde, lock-screen

anybody experienced this? I just locked my T460 with Ubuntu 16.04. There was this orange/red/yellow lock screen. I went away. After around 15 minutes I got back and all screens were black! (laptop screen, MiniDP and HDMI monitors). Neither keyboard or mouse woke it up. So I had to force shut it down by holding the button. I am checking /var/log/syslog and from the time when i locked it I can see it being spammed with these

```
Oct 14 09:34:48 vitas-ThinkPad-T460 org.kde.KScreen[4063]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_OutputProperty (ignored)
Oct 14 09:34:48 vitas-ThinkPad-T460 org.kde.KScreen[4063]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Output:  67
Oct 14 09:34:48 vitas-ThinkPad-T460 org.kde.KScreen[4063]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011Property:  Backlight
Oct 14 09:34:48 vitas-ThinkPad-T460 org.kde.KScreen[4063]: kscreen.xcb.helper: #011State (newValue, Deleted):  0
```

The last messages before I force shut it down were

```
Oct 14 09:50:33 vitas-ThinkPad-T460 systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Oct 14 09:50:33 vitas-ThinkPad-T460 colord[1393]: (colord:1393): Cd-WARNING **: failed to get session [pid 29844]: No such device or address
```

Any idea what it means?

EDIT: ps ax | grep -e dm -e saver

```
  180 ?        S<     0:00 [rtsx_pci_sdmmc_]
  280 ?        S<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  314 ?        S      0:11 [dmcrypt_write]
  324 ?        S<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  329 ?        S<     0:00 [kdmflush]
  363 ?        S      0:05 [jbd2/dm-1-8]
 1342 ?        SLsl   0:00 /usr/sbin/lightdm
 1394 tty7     Rsl+ 1091:38 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
 1771 ?        SLl    0:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
 5149 ?        S      0:02 /bin/bash /opt/ibm/Sametime/shared/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.activitymonitor.gtk.linux.x86_9.0.0.20160113-0633/watchscreensaver
21029 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto -e dm -e saver
```

Comment: Could you post the output put of `ps ax | grep -e dm -e saver`

Comment: added into question

Comment: Does it happen if you ran `xset -dpms` before locking it?

Comment: Almost certainly the problem is with  what the IBM Sametime shell script `watchscreensaver` is doing. There is an ongoing issue with sleep on Thinkpads, using hibernate or an alternate sleep mode is seen to work for some, see eg [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100171) or [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1530476).

FWIW: The kscreen output in syslog is just telling the system to turn the backlight off (does it go off?). The "last messages" you posted from CUPS and colord are to do with printing and with colour management respectively.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. I did not do any xset. What backlight? Seems like a keyboard backlight. Not sure about it if it switches off :-)